# Concatenated Where clause with array of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am wondering if there is a way to create a concatenated WHERE clause using an array of int.  I need to get the results for the entire array combined.  Can I do something like:

```
public ViewResult Results(int? programId, int? programYear, int? programTypeId, string toDate, string fromDate, int?[] programTypeIdList, int?[] programIdList)
{
    surveyResponseRepository.Get().Any(x => x.ProgramId == programIdList);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx):

```
surveyResponseRepository.Get().Any(x => programIdList.Contains(x.ProgramId));
```

Though that will tell you if ANY result meets that criteria.

I suspect you want to use `Where` instead of `Any`:

```
surveyResponseRepository.Get().Where(x => programIdList.Contains(x.ProgramId));
```

Also, why are you using an array of nullable `int`s?  If you're trying to make the parameter optional, just leave it as an array of regular `int`s and check for null:

```
public ViewResult Results(int? programId, int? programYear, int? programTypeId, string toDate, string fromDate, int[] programTypeIdList, int[] programIdList)
{
    return surveyResponseRepository.Get()
        .Where(x => programIdList == NULL 
                    || programIdList.Contains(x.ProgramId));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
public ViewResult Results(int? programId, int? programYear, int? programTypeId, string toDate, string fromDate, int?[] programTypeIdList, int?[] programIdList) 
{
     surveyResponseRepository.Get().Where(x => programIdList.HasValue && programIdList.Value.Contains(x.ProgramId)); 
}
```